# How to exclude rule 930120 for google oauth

Tags: mod-security

I've this error:

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `PmFromFile' with parameter `lfi-os-files.data' against variable `ARGS:scope' (Value: `email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/useri (16 characters omitted)' ) [file "/usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI.conf"] [line "84"] [id "930120"] [rev "4"] [msg "OS File Access Attempt"] [data "Matched Data: .profile found within ARGS:scope: email profile https:/www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https:/www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.0.0"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-lfi"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/FILE_INJECTION"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-33"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A4"] [tag "PCI/6.5.4"] [hostname "a.a.a.a"] [uri "/***/create_account_oauth.php"] [unique_id "159608684932.394214"] [ref "o53,8v144,116t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni,t:normalizePathWin,t:lowercase"
```

and I've created this exclusion rule for that:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /***/create_account_oauth.php" \
        "phase:2,log,pass,id:19023,ctl:ruleRemoveById=930120"
```

what I'd like to do is to refine the exclusion for googleapis only. I'm think chaining the rule with another one to match googleapis in the data field. Is that what you'd recommend? It seems difficult to find resource on chaining. Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should better define your question. Eg. how do you want to catch the "googleapis data field"? And what's your question about the chained rule?

Here is a good example (chained rule by 4 rules): https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/rules/REQUEST-903.9002-WORDPRESS-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf#L646-L667

Comment: @airween Question is already well defined, in case someone not understand, does not it mean, its not well explained.

Take me positively ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SecRule ARGS:scope "@contains [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%22) "id:'9000000',phase:2,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:ruleRemoveById=930120"

new mod security rule need to update

which enable google oauth login